# C# how to format a value taken from text box?

Tags: c#, string, format, streamwriter

this may be simple but im still new to this language.

I'm creating a windows application where is a text box and a a button. What it will do is take the value entered in the text box and create a .txt file with the value entered in the textbox as its content.

I've don this. I have successfully add "5" to the textbox and pressed the button and it will create a txt file with content "5" in it.

My question is, how do I format the value form the text box to something like this xxxxxxx.xxxxx?

So if I enter `5` how do I make it create in text to become `0000005.00000`?

Or if I enter `5.4` how do i make it become like this `0000005.40000`?

Can anyone shed a light? Or coding sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a text box gives you the value as a (text) *string*. If you want to process it further as a *number* (which you do), you first need to convert (parse) it. Then, you just format the number [the way you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx):

```
var number = Decimal.Parse(textBox.Text);
writer.Write(number.ToString("{0:0000000.00000}", number));
```

Comment: Thanx mate! easy, straight forward and spot on!

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to parse the string from the `TextBox` into a double and then format it back to string using `NumberFormatInfo`.

To parse the string, use:

```
Double d;
Double.TryParse("5.4", out d);
```

To format to what you want, have a look at these docs and choose the format that you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This blog post is good for how to use string.Format - http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Also MSDN is very helpful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

For example, "if using i enter 5.4 and how do i make it become like this 0000005.40000?":

Take a look at that MSDN link, under heading "The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier":

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D8"));
// Displays -00012345
```

Take a look at that MSDN link, under heading "The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier"

```
integerNumber = -29541;
Console.WriteLine(integerNumber.ToString("F3", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays -29541.000
```

But actually, to achieve what you're looking for then you are probably best using a format string like:

```
var f = 5.4;
f.ToString("000000000.0000000000000");
// Displays 000000005.4000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse your `TextBox` text into a double variable (using `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`) and try something like this:

```
double d = 5.0d;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0000000.00000}",d));
d = 5.4d;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0000000.00000}",d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
int number = 5;
string content = number.ToString("0000000.00000");
```

Comment: and what about 5.4, that doesn't really go into an `int` :)

Answer (score 0):

Look up `string.Format()`:

http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/